# Remove visual attribute in block in oracle forms 6

Tags: forms, oracle, block

A small question. How can I remove the visual attribute of some colums in my block? I have created a checkbox which can manipulate the background color of a field in the block.

Now if I select a 'manipulated' record, the 'Current Record Visual Attribute Group' doesn't work anymore. The new color will overrule it.

In the 'when_new_record_instance' of the block, I have specified this code:

```
set_item_property('block.item1', visual_attribute, '');
set_item_property('block.item2', visual_attribute, '');
set_item_property('block.item3', visual_attribute, '');
set_item_instance_property('block.item1', current_record, visual_attribute, 'selected');
set_item_instance_property('block.item2', current_record, visual_attribute, 'selected');
set_item_instance_property('block.item3', current_record, visual_attribute, 'selected');
```

With 'selected' being the visual attribute for the selected record.

But when I navigate to a new record, the old records will still have the color of the 'selected' visual attribute.

The solution might be very obvious, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance,

Walle

Comment: I wrote a solution for this particular issue some time back: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2010/07/27/current-record-visual-attribute-problem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got a solution. Not sure if it is the best one, but I created a procedure which sets the colors (like I did before in the post query). I call that procedure in the 'post_record' trigger on my block, and it works as I want it.

So in fact, the system recolors the colums again when I navigate to another row.